# Load UIimage only once form viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am new in IOS Development.I am downloading image on login view by using GCD and displaying on main 
menu i am displaying it but when i called another view from form main menu and come back to main menu it load again and again.i am storing image in AppDelegate.if u suggest me new thing i am thankful to you.

```
[super viewDidLoad];
logoimage.image=self.appDelegate.productImage;
```

Comment: Please cache the image

Comment: You might be initializing your view controller everytime because of which viewDidLoad is called everytime.

Comment: use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) it would solve your problem

Comment: cache image where and how?can you give me example or link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try overriding the getter for `productImage` in `AppDelegate`.

```
- (UIImage*)productImage 
{
    if (!_productImage) {
        _productImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name.png"];
    }

    return _productImage;
}
```

This will ensure the image is only initialized once, and simply accessed when called thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

if you cached the image,
you can also called in viewWillAppear.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    logoimage.image=self.appDelegate.productImage
}
```